# Как загрузить в select значения option из приложения

Tags: java, html, jquery, servlet

У меня есть приложение, которое при запуске выгружает из базы данных небольшой строковый массив и хранит его в классе, допустим, `Cache`. Как значения этого массива подставить в html страницу в качестве значений тэга `option` внутри тэга `select`? Мне для этого нужно создать сервлет, который передаст этот массив из класса `Cache` на страницу? Или надо использовать `jQuery`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В сервлете формируете тело ответа

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

out.println("<html><body>");
// Ваш код
out.println("<select>");

for(String s : Cash[]){  
     out.println("<option value='"+s+"'>"+s" +</option>");
}
out.println("</select>");
 // Ваш код

out.println("</body></html>");
```